# Bootstrap 4 Navigation - Mobile View

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following header, which includes a Bootstrap 4 Navigation:

```
<div class="header container-fluid">

  <div class="row">



<div class="brand col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">
  Logo
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">

  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Welcome<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown_angebot" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Pricing
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_angebot">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown_unternehmen" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Our Company
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_unternehmen">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">History</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Career</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Clients</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Get here<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

  </div>
</div>
```

I have made a few changes, since I wanted to navigation items to be centered and stretch to the very outset of the row / col. However, now my mobile navigation does not work anymore, and I have no clue why that is.

Here is the SASS for my Navigation:

```
.brand {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  height: 100px;
}

.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white !important;
  padding: 0 !important;

  .navbar-nav {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      list-style: none;

      .nav-link {
        padding: 0 !important;
      }

      li {
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: center;

        a {
          // background-color: yellow;
          display: block;

        }

      }

      li:first-child {
        text-align: left;
      }

      li:last-child {
        text-align: right;
      }




    .nav-item {
      // margin: 30px;

    }
  }
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/fmz6hafz/

Everything is now aligned horizontally, also in the mobile view. How can I revert this and get the original bootstrap mobile view back?

Comment: can you please create fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net

Comment: I edited my post! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

You have used wrong syantax to comment in css file `//` this is causing to fail your css from that line see

```
  a {
      // background-color: yellow;
      display: block;

    }
```

use should use like this to comment in css `/*background-color: yellow;*/` else removed unwanted code.

```css
.brand {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  height: 100px;
}

.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white !important;
  padding: 0 !important;

  .navbar-nav {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      list-style: none;

      .nav-link {
        padding: 0 !important;
      }

      li {
      display: table-cell;
      text-align: center;

        a {
        
          display: block;

        }

      }

      li:first-child {
        text-align: left;
      }

      li:last-child {
        text-align: right;
      }




    .nav-item {
            
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<body>
<div class="header container-fluid">

  <div class="row">



<div class="brand col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">
  Logo
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded col-sm-10 offset-sm-1">

  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">

      <li class="nav-item active">  
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Welcome<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown_angebot" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Pricing
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_angebot">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown_unternehmen" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Our Company
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown_unternehmen">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">History</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Career</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Clients</a>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Get here<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

  </div>
</div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Could you describe what exactly you've changed? The result looks like what i want, however, when I implement it on my machine, it does not change and everything is still horizontal.

Comment: I did nothing just removed commented css, `//` this is not a valid comment syntax for css so causing to fail. use `/* */` to comment